# always entityManager = null

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, junit, persistence

I can’t test entityManager in unit test

@PersistenceContextprivate EntityManager entityManager;

always entityManager = null

```
@Repository
public class IRepositoryImpl {

@PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
public I findI(){
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
....
}
....
}
```

The unit test:

```
private IRepositoryImpl iRepositoryImpl ;

@Test
void findITest(){
     I i = iRepositoryImpl.findI();
...
}
```

> java.lang.NullPointerException
> entityManager = null

Comment: And with those 2 snippets you expect us to suddenly know what is wrong? Please add the full test and service class.

Comment: Can you upload your project to a public repository or put here spring configurations?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below in your unit test class:

```
    import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
    import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
    
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest(classes = SpringBootApplicationClass.class) //annotation when you need Spring Boot features
```

Comment: You don't know as he didn't post his testcase he might be trying or wanting something totally different.